# Is this After Delete Trigger correct?

Tags: sqlite

I'm working with a music database and am trying to make a trigger that recreates the exact track information that was deleted from the database if the title of the album the track is in contains 'Nirvana'. The trigger ignores the deletion of any track not contained in a 'Nirvana' album.

```
CREATE TRIGGER UndeleteLostTrack 
AFTER DELETE on Track
WHEN (SELECT Album.Title
      FROM Album a, Track t
      WHERE a.AlbumID = t.AlbumID
        AND a.Title LIKE '%NIRVANA%')
BEGIN
    INSERT into Track(TrackID, Name, AlbumID, MediaTypeID, GenreID, Composer, Millisecond, Byte, UnitPrice)
    VALUES (OLD.TrackID, OLD.Name, OLD.AlbumID, OLD.MediaTypeID, OLD.GenreID, OLD.Composer, OLD.Millisecond, OLD.Byte, OLD.UnitPrice);
END;
```

Trigger gets created but not sure if it's doing what it's meant to.

Comment: please provide code examples

Comment: Sorry, have added now

Comment: What happens when you test it?